# How to excludes some files in rsync

Tags: rsync

I am backing up data from a folder in MAC.
The MAC unnecessarily creates some files startinmg with . like

```
.dsdfsd or ._hjdds
```

Now i want to exclude the files starting with . in rsync .

How can i do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search in the [rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for "exclude", you will find:

> --exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN

So this would probably work:

```
rsync --exclude='.*' [other arguments]
```

Comment: Think `exclude` supports regular expressions, so you'd have to escape the '.' like `exclude='\.*'.  You might also want to use an exclude file if you have a lot of conditions to match.

Comment: @gravyface: No, it's similar to globbing, from the man page: "Here are some examples of exclude/include matching:  “- *.o” would exclude all names matching *.o".

Answer (score 1):

I would replace Dennis's regex with

```
--exclude='.??*'
```

The ".*" pattern got me into a lot of trouble way back in my youth, when I tried to remove all of the hidden files from someone's home directory...

```
rm -rf .*
```

Is ***NOT*** a good thing to do. (Here's a hint: .* matches ..)

**[EDIT]**

Thanks to Dennis commenting on this, you can disregard my warning (though I'm leaving the comment to show that I'm doubly an idiot) ;-)

Comment: It's similar to globbing rather than a regex. In rsync, `.*` doesn't match `..` and *excluding* `..` is safer than *including* it which is what your `rm` did.  Even an explicit include doing `rsync --include '..' * dest` knows that you didn't really mean it. Also, your `.??*` would allow (not exclude) short filenames such as `.aa`.  (However, your point is really about good habits.)

Comment: Nice, thanks! I thought rsync used regexes rather than globbing...but then there's probably a flag for that :-) I appreciate the info!